# how to generate markers using an api in vue-2-leaflet

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet

I'm trying to generate markers using an api. Right now I can get the api fine and I have it stored in a variable but I just can't get the markers to show up. I'm using a v-for loop to display all of the markers.

any help would be appreciated

heres my code

```html
<template>
  <div class="containerTest">
    <div style="height: 80vh">
    <LMap :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
      <LTileLayer :url="url"></LTileLayer>
      <l-marker
        :key="index"
        v-for="(brew, index) in markers"
          :lat-lng="latLng(brew.latitude, brew.longitude)"
      ></l-marker>
    </LMap>
  </div>
  </div>

</template>
      
<script>

import { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker } from "vue2-leaflet";

export default {
  name: "Map",
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LMarker
  },
  data() {
    return {
      markers: [],
      url: "https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=CFmlXsYmVozAdWKEtdT5",
      zoom: 6,
      center: [46.5322, 2.9482],
      bounds: null
    };
  },
  mounted: function () {
    fetch('https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries').then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    }).then(json=>{
        this.brews = json
        console.log(this.brews)
    })
  },
  methods: {
    latLng: function(lat, lng) {
      return L.latLng(lat,lng);
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any errors in your console?

Some things I noticed:

1. In your class, there is no property *brews*. There is *markers* instead.

   Change `this.brews = json` to `this.markers = json`
2. I checked the API and it returns *null* in *latitude*, *longitude* for most of your objects. Ι would add a `v-if` to check if values exist.